# 10 years on StackExchange

Tags: discussion

This was our first question ever posted on Tridion Stack Exchange: [How to design a recursive menu schema](https://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/1/how-to-design-a-recursive-menu-schema).

With hindsight, it's great that it is a *timeless* question, about design patterns rather than a certain API call that could be linked to a specific version.

Now that we've been using this platform for nearly 10 years, what questions (or answers) would you like to highlight? Which epic responses (or comment debates) do you think *everyone* should read?

Share the links below.

Answer (score 4):

Here's my list:

- [The day that Google broke Tridion](https://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/7247/chrome-36-with-tridion-2011-or-2013).
- [The age-old question about how to fix what Tridion "knows" about your content](https://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/3/how-can-we-resync-what-the-tridion-cm-thinks-are-published-to-a-specific-publica)

And of course, this wouldn't be a developer-focused community if we wouldn't talk about ordinal positions and the eternal fight around using 0 or 1 to identify the first element of a collection...

- [Ordinal position of a component presentation](https://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/83/ordinal-position-of-a-component-presentation-in-a-dwt)

What do these questions have in common? Lots of discussions.

Answer (score 3):

Anything by [Alex Klock](https://tridion.stackexchange.com/users/9/alex-klock). Even his decade-old answers about GUI extensions are still solid.

Makes me wonder who will step up to be the new Alex when T10 comes out.

Comment: It'll be hard to beat Alex prime. Maybe it'd have to be an AI. :-P

Answer (score 2):

I'd like to highlight my question about [Example Tridion Reports](https://tridion.meta.stackexchange.com/q/389/46) on Tridion Meta as an **example of the trust and transparency we have in the community**, with an open approach that takes time and effort to build and maintain. Answers are still welcome!

*I won't say that question caused waves, per se, but I recall people wondering what I was doing by asking such a question in a public forum. :-)*

Here are some other highlights.

For great answers (though not always *mine*) with some friendly banter including my favorite comment, "WTF just accept it immediately alvin :)" see:

- [How to Add SDL Media Manager to the Slide-out Navigation?](https://tridion.stackexchange.com/q/7333/46)
- [Which Element or CSS selector to use for custom CME logo?](https://tridion.stackexchange.com/q/11579/46)
- [Organizing CMS folders](https://tridion.stackexchange.com/q/11212/46)

As examples of in-depth Translation Manager insights, see:

- [Typical Translation Manager system user (ServiceTcmUserName)?](https://tridion.stackexchange.com/q/21717/46)
- [Translation Manager .NET API v2 - what's the new "SystemConfiguration"](https://tridion.stackexchange.com/q/18317/46)
- [Where is Translation Manager configuration cached (what to restart)?](https://tridion.stackexchange.com/q/21414/46)
- [Translation Job Behavior - UN-localization?](https://tridion.stackexchange.com/q/8520/46)

*There are too many others to list, but I particularly enjoy when someone with [Will](https://tridion.stackexchange.com/users/54/will-price) or [Mihai](https://tridion.stackexchange.com/users/45/mihai-c%C4%83dariu)'s expertise asks something new and we get both an answer and some insights from [Peter Kjaer](https://tridion.stackexchange.com/users/141/peter-kjaer), [Rick](https://tridion.stackexchange.com/users/1322/rick-pannekoek), or others within RWS.*

As a final highlight, [this answer from community member](https://tridion.stackexchange.com/a/21724/46) and company alum Lars, came in *after* a change of companies. And he's not the only one!

Comment: Thank you and Quirjin for sharing these stories and links. Congratulations to you all. I love reading these posts.